# Does Craft Commerce support multi-currency?

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce, currency

After looking at the [Features page](https://craftcommerce.com/features) for Craft Commerce, I didn't see anything regarding multi-currency support. Is this something that's available for certain payment processors?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is now available as of Commerce 1.2.1323

https://craftcommerce.com/changelog#build1323

https://craftcommerce.com/docs/payment-currencies

Answer (score 2):

Not at this time (version 1.1), but Pixel & Tonic has indicated in Craft Slack that it is on the roadmap.